# JAX-RS Bean Validation Error Message Internationalization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a SpringBoot app. with a bean wit this property:

```
@Positive(message = "{signup.form.error.city.missing}")
private Long regionId;
```

but if there is an error I see this on the browser:

```
{signup.form.error.city.missing}
```

not the value of the property file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use custom name messages in a properties file like you need to define a **`LocalValidatorFactoryBean`** and register the `messageSource`:

```
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public WebMvcConfiguration(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

It will now see the value you defined in the `property` file.